# Preserving alternate row shades on a table with a sticky column

Tags: html, css

I have implemented a table with a sticky column that includes the following css:

```
tr {
    display: flex;
    height: 56px;
    background: white;
    &:nth-of-type(even) {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    }
}
tr>td:first-of-type {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 244px;
    max-width: 244px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

This gives me alternate row shades:

[image]

But when scrolling horizontally, content bleeds through into the first stick column:

[image]

If I set a background colour on my `first-of-type` rule explicitly then I dont get this behaviour, e.g.

```
tr>td:first-of-type {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  min-width: 244px;
  max-width: 244px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

But I want to preserve the alternate row shades as per my `tr` rule. I wondered if I could combine nth-of-type with my first-of-type rule, e.g.

```
tr>td:first-of-type {
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background: white;
      min-width: 244px;
      max-width: 244px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
      &:nth-of-type(even) {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
      }
    }
```

This doesnt work, I have probably misunderstood something! Whats the solution here?

Thanks

Comment: for the first col, do not use rgba() colors, use a plain color so what's behind is hidden.... + z-index eventually

Comment: @G-Cyr could you offer an example of what you had in mind? I have changed to plain colours and tried a z-index on my nth-of-type selector but not had any luck

Comment: can you provide a working code showing your issue . We can help from there ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for you.

> **Method 1**

- Applied `background: white;` to sticky columns (i.e
  `tr>td:first-of-type`)
- Then applied `style="background:#dddddd"` to even columns of `tr>td:first-of-type`.

That's it. :)

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width:150px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr>td:first-of-type {
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background: white;
      min-width: 244px;
      max-width: 244px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#dddddd">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#dddddd">Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#dddddd">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **Method 2**

- I have taken table into `<div class="scroll">` and applied scroll to
  it instead of applying to table.
- Then took this whole div into another div i.e `<div class="wrapper">` here and applied `position:relative` to it.
- Applied `position:absolute` instead of `position:sticky` to `tr>td:first-of-type`
- For alternate backgruond color I have applied inline `style="background:#dddddd"` to columns of `tr>td:first-of-type`.
- Rest is in below snippet.

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width:100px;    
    height:50px;    
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


tr {
    display: flex;
    background: white; 
}

tr>td:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    min-width: 244px;
    max-width: 244px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ababab;
}

.scroll {
    margin-left: 244px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="scroll">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ababab;">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ababab;">Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ababab;">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

**Hope this helps :)**